# spring security can't login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is snippet from my spring security configuration:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/zaloguj" default-target-url="/"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
                         authentication-failure-url="/zaloguj?error"
                         login-processing-url="/login"

            />
    <security:logout logout-url="/wyloguj"
                     invalidate-session="true"
                     logout-success-url="/"
            />
</security:http>


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" password="admin"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

When I type in login form admin admin I am redirected to authentication-failure-url. What am I doing wrong? I am using Spring Security version 3.2.0.RELEASE. Thanks in advance for any help. Best Regards

Comment: 1. what does your 'loginSuccessHandler' does? 2. what is the url you try to access, before you get to the login page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try activating the debug logging for Spring security.

The following configuration works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="test" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

My logging configuration (log4j.properties)

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG,stdout
```

And following are the debug statement printed on successful login

```
2014-03-09 03:56:08 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:205 - Request is to process authentication
.........
2014-03-09 03:56:08 DEBUG SessionFixationProtectionStrategy:97 - Started new session: bq2ozweuwq07l16o2nspj4q3
2014-03-09 03:56:08 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:319 - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bf69f27c: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 1ajcb4rxv6p4ryg58262el5e8; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
..................
2014-03-09 03:56:08 DEBUG SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler:107 - Using default Url: /welcome
2014-03-09 03:56:08 DEBUG DefaultRedirectStrategy:36 - Redirecting to '/welcome'
```

Comment: Thanks for log4j configuration. With enabled debug I figured out that in my login form I don't had valid names for input. Thanks for help. They should be j_password and j_username and url action must be set to /j_spring_security_check.

Comment: Glad to help ! Actually you can override the parameter names and the form post url as well. But then you would need to extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter with your own version
and set up the filter in configuration. For reference you can look here http://mark.koli.ch/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url