# Spring security does not allow users to sign in, it does not show any errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Once user navigates to signin page and regardless of using correct or wrong usernames and passwords, Spring Security shows following error message. I reviewed following questions but still have the same error [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271645/spring-security-cant-login),[2](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/),[3](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/)

```
 Your login attempt was not successful due to
```

I am using `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, to encode new users passwords.

**LoginForm**

```
<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">
            <font color="red"> Your login attempt was not successful due
                to <br />
            <br /> <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />.
            </font>
        </c:if>
                <c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
                    Invalid username and password.
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="error">${error}</div>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                    <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
                </c:if>
               <form id="form-login" role="form" method="post"
                        action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />"
                        class="relative form form-default">
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

**my-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/Project" />
        <property name="username" value="test1" />
        <property name="password" value="test1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        depends-on="dataSource">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.projec.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
            expression="execution(* com.project.service.*Service.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
    </aop:config>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">



    <beans:import resource='login-service.xml' />
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="permitAll" />


        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login login-page="/signin" default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/signin?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myMemberDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**MyMemberDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class MyMemberDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private MemberRepository memberRep;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Member member = memberRep.findByUserName(username);
        HashSet<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
        roles.add("ROLE_MEMBER");
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(roles);
        return buildUserForAuthentication(member, authorities);

    }

    private User buildUserForAuthentication(Member member,
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(member.getUsername(), member.getPassword(),
                member.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<String> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(
                setAuths);

        return Result;
    }

}
```

**Spring version**

```
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a custom implementation of UserDetailsService. Can you provide the code for MemberDetailsService?

Comment: @greyfox I just included UserDetailsService thanks

Comment: Assuming that you are using spring-security 3.2.x - the default form-action url should be `/login` (instead of `j_spring_security_check`)

Comment: @fateddy when I use /login it redirects to /login and shows 404 error.

Comment: You are using /j_spring_security_check to post your login form. Try with your custom login (/sigin) page.

Comment: Unfortunately I was wrong - see @JEY's comment - you configured your login-page to `signin` (so change the form action to that URL). Make sure your input-fields for `username` and `password` should be named like that. If you still encounter login set the logger-treshold to ALL for `org.springframework.security`.

Comment: @fateddy I used /signin but it still does not work. where should I set value of logger-treshold?

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging

Comment: @fateddy I added log4j dependency but it does not show any error.

Comment: You also need to configure log4j - by placing a `log4j.properties` (or `log4j.xml`) in your classpath. See this blog-post: http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/

Comment: I have log4j.properties in WebContent folder but it does not show any errors.

Comment: what exception did you  received ? Please check by enable debugging in spring. logger name for spring is "org.springframework".  also check console logs ( container logs )

Comment: @KunalSurana I have log4j.properties in webcontent folder and related dependencies but nothing is displayed in the console.

Comment: add following in log4j.properties   log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG,stdout and log4j.properties should be placed at WEB-INF/classes location

Comment: @KunalSurana there is no classes folder in WEB-INF

Comment: if you are using eclipse then put your log4j.properties in src source folder or in lib directory.

Comment: @KunalSurana I am using Eclipse, and put the properties file in WEB-INF/lib folder but still nothing is displayed in console. My properties file has log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG,stdout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103581/discussion-between-kunal-surana-and-daniel-newtown).

Comment: Just to confirm, where you inject  MemberRepository? In the way that it's represented won't work.

Comment: @DanielNewtown What do you mean by "when I submit the form nothing happens." Are you redirected somewhere ? What address shows in the browser address bar ?

Answer (score 0):

You configured your login page with

```
<form-login login-page="/signin" default-target-url="/index"
 authentication-failure-url="/signin?error" username-parameter="username"
 password-parameter="password" />
```

But your form post action is : `<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />`
it should like following

```
<form method="POST" action="@{/signin}" role="form">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>        
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>    
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

check the details of [`Custom login using spring-security`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html)

Comment: you added method="post" twice.